# How to run OpenCvSharp on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: c#, opencv, ubuntu

I have a problem with running OpenCvShare on the Ubuntu Linux. It keeps saying that libOpenCvSharpExtern is not found.

I have a problem with running OpenCvSharp on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 x64. I have created a .NET Core/Standard solution (Standard is a library project, Core is the runner). The library project references Nuget packages:
OpenCvSharp4 (4.0.0.20181225)
OpenCvSharp4.runtime.ubuntu.18.04-x64 (4.0.0.20181225).

Then, after a succesfull compilation, I published the runner project using:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r ubuntu.18.04-x64
```

The, when I run the executable on Ubuntu, following error is thrown:

`Unhandled Exception: OpenCvSharp.OpenCvSharpException: Failed to create VideoCapture System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OpenCvSharp.NativeMethods' threw an exception. OpenCvSharp.OpenCvSharpException: Unable to load shared library 'OpenCvSharpExtern' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libOpenCvSharpExtern: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory ---> System.DllNotFoundException: 
Unable to load shared library 'OpenCvSharpExtern' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libOpenCvSharpExtern: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The file libOpenCvSharpExtern.so is in the same path that the executable, I have copied it inside usr/local/lib as well, and id didn't help. Aplication is meant to detect faces based on the camera feed.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: I have even succesfult compiled opencv and opencvsharp on Ubunty 18.04 and even then it is not detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have finally got it running. The problem was in include path. When you execute 
`ldd libOpenCvSharpExtern.so` from terminal in path that lib resides, it will output all referenced libraries this one uses. Initially I had full list of "not found" references. All missing libraries were already installed in `/usr/local/lib`. It turned out, that this path is not a default path where system is looking for libraries. 
[Link to a question on ubuntu forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165027/why-cant-my-program-find-the-libraries-in-usr-local-lib)

After I added 
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib"` environment variable and restarted system, everything started working, and using `ldd` on the libOpenCvSharpExtern.so library showed clearly, that all libraries were found.